# Implementing shopify with braintree android

Tags: shopify, braintree

Has anyone implemented shopify with Braintree , i know you have to enable it in shopify account , and you have an option to make a checkout on google chrome , but has anyone done it inside app ?

Any help is really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using webview(open the particular link).The shopify does not provide the SDK for that....